# ¿Cómo hacer un contador en Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

Soy nuevo en programación, estoy haciendo un juego en el cual quiero contar los puntos, tengo un `int` como contador pero no se como conectarlo para que me muestre los puntos en [QLCDNumber](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html).
muchas gracias.

Este es con un [QSpinBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html) pero solo funciona con el tiempo no con una variable.

```
connect(tiempo, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTiempo()));
void Arcanoid::onTiempo() {
    ui->spinBox->setValue(ui->spinBox->value() + 1);
}
```

y tengo la función:

```
void Arcanoid::Colision()
{
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
            if (l[i][j]->collidesWithItem(bola)) {
                pantalla->removeItem(l[i][j]);
                contador = contador + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            if (bola->collidesWithItem(l2[i][j])) {
                pantalla->removeItem(l2[i][j]);
                contador = contador + 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

quiero que en lugar del tiempo se tome el contador

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo a la pregunta asi te podriamos ayudar mas rapido.

Comment: @gilbertoquintero ya le he subido

Comment: Te recomendaria que viera s primero c si eres nuevo en el mundo de la programacion la verdad te ayudaria mucho entender las bases de c y c++

Answer (score 1):

Si eres nuevo en programación hay miles de ejercicios a realizar antes de meterse a programar un juego... es preferible entender y dominar primero las bases porque un juego no es algo baladí. Además ten en cuenta que aprender a programar C++ puede ser bastante frustrante si no se entiende el lenguaje.

Ahora bien, tu quieres que el *spinbox* muestre el valor de una variable, ¿cierto? vale, pues con el poco código que has puesto entiendo que debería ser tan sencillo como dejar la línea así:

```
void Arcanoid::onTiempo(){
    ui->spinBox->setValue(contador);
}
```

Esto asumiendo que la variable `contador` sea de tipo entero.